# Does a port expander with built-in optocouplers exist?

Tags: opto-isolator

I want to control a lot of LEDs via a Raspberry Pi. My current idea is to use MCP23017 chips together with optocouplers to protect the Raspberry Pi and the chips. This is the schematics I have in my head, I've drawn only 4 of the 16 optocouplers and LEDs:

[image: MCP23017 connected to optocouplers]
This should work fine. But it takes a lot of space on my breadboard and I have to place a lot of wires. So I thought, maybe there is a port expanding chip that has opcouplers built-in. Because in my schematic all the transistor emitters are connected to each other, such a port expander would only need one more pin than a port expander without optocouplers.

Does a port expander with built-in optocouplers exist? Or any other ideas to reduce the amount of chips and wires?

Comment: Have you considered using actual LED drivers instead?

Comment: Protect against what? I suspect you do not actually need galvanic isolation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I don't think such a monolithic (or single package) device exists, and if it did it would be an off-topic shopping question.

You should have resistors in series with each of the LEDs on the optocoupler inputs, by the way, otherwise you are depending on the outputs to be weak enough not to overdrive the LEDs.

---

A better **design** approach might be to use a chip such as the [ISO1541](http://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/iso1540.pdf) to isolate the I2C and drive the LEDs directly from the port expander chip. The Microchip part is better at sinking current than sourcing it, so it's better to connect the LEDs between Vcc2 and the GPIO (with a series resistor, of course) than to GND.

[image]

So Vcc1 would be the 3.3V from your Pi and Vcc2 would be (or would be derived from) your LED supply on the other side of the galvanic isolation. This has the advantage that only 4 wires including the two power wires are directly connected to the Pi, everything else is isolated.

Comment: I'm gonna give it a try, this thing together with an I2C led driver